# cascading matrix in C#

Tags: c#

I am studying programming in the university and I'm using C#
They give us this algorithm as homework to do,
If any one knows how to solve this kind of algorithms please let me know,

Here we use a set of boxes numbered N that the user enters, box number 1 remains closed and we start with box number 2, we open it and then move also by 2, and so on until we reach the number N,
then we move to box number 3 if it is open we close it and if it is closed we open it, then we move  3 boxes and so we repeat the process until we reach N,
then we move to box No. 4, if it is open we close it and if it is closed we open it, then we move 4, we repeat until we reach N,
in the end we will print the status of the closed boxes will be 0 and the open box number will be printed

Open box = we will put the number of the box
Closing box = 0 (the original index in the array)

Example : N = 10
Array [10]
(10 closed boxes)

| Loop | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loop 1 starts with box 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Loop 2 starts with box 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 10 |
| Loop 3 starts with box 3 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| Loop 4 starts with box 4 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 10 |
| Loop 5 starts with box 5 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| Loop 6 starts with box 6 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| Loop 7 starts with box 7 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 |
| Loop 8 starts with box 8 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Loop 9 starts with box 9 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Loop 10 starts with box 10 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 10 |

Print : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 0 - 0 - 10

I wrote this code, I think the problem is how to increase the loop but i couldn't figure out how to do that

```
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] A = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            A[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int x = i + 1; x < n; x++)
            {
                if (A[x] == 0)
                {
                    A[x] = x + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    A[x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(A[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, note that arrays' are *zero-based*, i.e. array of length `10` has items with indexes `0, 1, ..., 9`;
so we have to add and subtract `1`:

```
  int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  // Array will be filled by zeros, not need to do it manually 
  int[] A = new int[n];

  for (int size = 2; size <= A.Length; ++size) 
    for (int i = size - 1; i < A.Length; i += size)
      A[i] = A[i] == 0 ? i + 1 : 0;

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", A));
```

If we input `10` the output will be

```
  0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 0 - 10
```

We can extract a method if we want to print out loops:

```
private static int[] MyLoop(int n, int index) {
  int[] A = new int[n];

  for (int size = 2; size <= index; ++size) 
    for (int i = size - 1; i < A.Length; i += size)
      A[i] = A[i] == 0 ? i + 1 : 0;

  return A;  
}
```

And then

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  Console.Write($"Loop #{i,3} : ");
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", MyLoops(n, i)));
}
```

**Outcome:**

```
Loop #  1 : 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0
Loop #  2 : 0 - 2 - 0 - 4 - 0 - 6 - 0 - 8 - 0 - 10
Loop #  3 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 8 - 9 - 10
Loop #  4 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 9 - 10
Loop #  5 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 9 - 0
Loop #  6 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 0 - 0 - 9 - 0
Loop #  7 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 0 - 9 - 0
Loop #  8 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 0
Loop #  9 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 0 - 0
Loop # 10 : 0 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 0 - 10
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a professional code 